Springboot web -application show some minor error Github link present
"I am experiencing difficulties in initiating this project as it is only partially built and is displaying some minor errors, despite the correctness of my code. If anyone could assist me in rectifying these issues, I have already pushed my code to GitHub."
Anyhelp would be grateful Thanks
Github link
You can clone and run on your IDE
I want to sucessfully run this minor project and it show some error while starting it
I just need to run this code

Questions should be self-contained. Code should be properly formatted inside the question. Please take the tour and check how to ask.

I have fixed it and created pull request https://github.com/vb51/Spring_user_management/pull/1
The main error you have is a layout of packages
For Spring Boot the packages with components should be inside a package with main class. In such way they will be scanned automatically
Also you missed @Service annotation for UserAccountService, that is why spring can not see it. You had typo in query, and so on. Please look at diff

Thanks, Alex That was a really silly mistake I made
But Now actually my data is not showing in my console or in my H2 database code and everything working fine you can check my HTML file in resource/templates folder can you please check it

Almost everything was OK except fields in index.html should be without prefix "user." Now it shows the page
